# Why do my properties show up as '[string contents] not found' during debug?

Tags: game-engine, properties

I`m pretty new to the BGE and I`m just getting to grip with Logic bricks

I recently attempted to create a property named `Next` (String) that holds the word `Up`, `Down`, `Left` or `Right` inside it depending on user inputs.

My problem is that `Up` is the default starting direction which seems fine; although as soon as I attempt to change it it becomes [Up/Left/Right/Down not found].

[image]

It seems like this problem is effecting other parts of logic that refer to the `Next` variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess I'm a little idiotic for not noticing but I've found my own answer and I guess I should leave it here for future reference!

When changing a strings data the word needed to be stored inside quotation marks (e.g -  "Up") or it won't work, hope this helps someone in the future.